# How can I specify a non-null default value for a Scalar Subquery?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query of the form:

```
SELECT 
col1,
col2,
(
SELECT my_value FROM my_second_table WHERE my_table.value = ...
) AS potentially_null_column

FROM my_first_table
```

When `SELECT my_value FROM my_second_table WHERE my_table.value = ...` returns no rows, then `potentially_null_column` is set to `null`.

This jibes with the Postgres docs on Scalar Subqueries: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES:

> But if, during a particular execution, the subquery returns no rows, there is no error; the scalar result is taken to be null.)

The problem is, I want `potentially_null_column` to be a string `'UNSET'` instead of `null` if there are no rows returned. Unfortunately, `coalesce` won't work here, since there are no rows returned to coalesce. How can I specify a non-null default value for a Scalar Subquery?

Comment: The problem is that since the subquery returns no rows, the coalesce never gets called.

Comment: Yes my bad, no coffee here.... I was in the process of editing the comment when you posted yours.

Comment: Assuming potentially_null_column is some type of string: `SELECT *, COALESCE((SELECT potentially_null_column FROM my_second_table WHERE [...]), 'UNSET') FROM my_first_table`. If it is e.g. a decimal, then you will be forced to decide a default value as decimal too (a column cannot return mixed type): `SELECT *, COALESCE((SELECT potentially_null_column FROM my_second_table WHERE [...]), 0) FROM my_first_table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, the `COALESCE` function is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT *,
       COALESCE((
          SELECT potentially_null_column
          FROM my_second_table
          WHERE [...]
       ), 'UNSET')
FROM my_first_table
```

SQL does not allow for mixed types to be returned in a single column, so if your data is not `VARCHAR`/`TEXT` and similar, you are not allows to return a constant string instead of `NULL`.
For instance, if your column is `INTEGER`/`NUMERIC`, you can replace `NULL` by `0`, not by `'UNSET'`:

```
SELECT *,
       COALESCE((
          SELECT potentially_null_column
          FROM my_second_table
          WHERE [...]
       ), 0)
FROM my_first_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine that with a [`union`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html): [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CJNcExBl)

```sql
SELECT  col1,
        col2,
        (SELECT _val FROM
         (SELECT 0 AS _order,coalesce(my_value,'FOUND UNSET') _val
          FROM my_second_table 
          WHERE my_table.value = v2
          UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS _order,'NOT FOUND' as _val) 
         ORDER BY _order LIMIT 1
         ) AS potentially_null_column
FROM my_first_table as my_table
```

| col1 | col2 | potentially_null_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | my_value_1 |
| 20 | 2 | NOT FOUND |
| 40 | 4 | FOUND UNSET |

If you just move `coalesce()` to wrap the scalar subquery from the outside, it'll work but it won't care whether it doesn't find a matching row at all, or if it *does* but with `my_value` set to `null` in it - in both cases it'll  report `'UNSET'` just the same, obscuring potentially important information:

```sql
SELECT  col1,
        col2,
        coalesce( (SELECT my_value FROM my_second_table WHERE my_table.value = v2)::text
                 ,'UNSET') AS potentially_null_column
FROM my_first_table as my_table
```

| col1 | col2 | potentially_null_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | my_value_1 |
| 20 | 2 | UNSET |
| 40 | 4 | UNSET |

`UNION` can let you differentiate between these cases, so you can use `coalesce()` inside the scalar subquery if it's `FOUND UNSET`, while failover value in `UNION` can give you `NOT FOUND`. If it doesn't matter or you intentionally wanted to merge the two cases, moving `coalesce()` up/out is enough.